# Does calculating d/dt of someething mean the same as calculating the derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Probably a dumb question but I missed college for a week due to sickness. The exercise I have to do is: d/dt eight root of t^7.

Does this simply mean I have to calculate the derivative of the eight root of t^7?

Comment: Yes. Just don't forget to mention that you're calculating the derivative with respect to $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Another common notation that you will find besides $\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left[\sqrt[8]{t^{7}}\right]$ is $\left(\sqrt[8]{t^{7}}\right)^{\prime}$ (which personally I'm not a fan of).